# How to extract a number into digits using R?

Tags: r, numbers, extract, digits

Suppose I have a number: 4321

and I want to extract it into digits: 4, 3, 2, 1

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  The **strings** `4321` or `1` are different from the **numbers**  `4321` and `1`

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, with `strsplit`:

```
x <- as.character(4321)
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "")))
[1] 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `substring` to extract character at each index and then convert it back to integer:

```
x <- 4321
as.integer(substring(x, seq(nchar(x)), seq(nchar(x))))
[1] 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 5):

For **real** fun, here's an absurd method:

```r
digspl <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(x >= 0)  # doesn't work for negative numbers

  x <- trunc(x) # just in case
  
  if (x < 10) return(x)  # make it work for 1-digit numbers

  mj <- trunc(log10(x))
  y <- trunc(x / 10 ^ mj)
  for (j in 1:mj) {
    y[j + 1] <- trunc((x - y[j] * 10 ^ (mj - j + 1)) / (10 ^ (mj - j)))
    x <-  x - y[j] * 10 ^ (mj - j + 1)
  }
  return(y)
}
```

Comment: ZOMG people are voting this up?  What is this, /. moderation? :-)

Comment: @Oliver, nice upgrade but...  it was never intended as a serious answer!

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's an alternative:

```
x <- 4321
read.fwf(textConnection(as.character(x)), rep(1, nchar(x)))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 
# 1  4  3  2  1
```

The only advantage I can think of is the possibility of exploding your input into varying widths, though I guess you can do that with substring too.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, using modulo operator:

```
get_digit <- function(x, d) {
    # digits from the right
    # i.e.: first digit is the ones, second is the tens, etc.
    (x %% 10^d) %/% (10^(d-1))
}

# for one number
get_all_digit <- function(x) {
    get_digit_x <- function(d) get_digit(x,d)
    sapply(nchar(x):1, get_digit_x) 
}

# for a vector of numbers
digits <- function(x) {
    out <- lapply(x, get_all_digit)
    names(out) <- x
    out
}
```

Example:

```
> digits(100:104)
$`100`
[1] 1 0 0

$`101`
[1] 1 0 1

$`102`
[1] 1 0 2

$`103`
[1] 1 0 3

$`104`
[1] 1 0 4
```